# Integral of the absolute value of a given function

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, fourier-analysis

For each $t \in (-\infty,0]$, consider the following integral:
$$f(t,x) = -2t\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2}}e^{-i\langle p, x\rangle}e^{-t^{2}(|p|^{2}+1)}dp.$$
In the above formula, $\langle p,x\rangle = p_{1}x_{1}+p_{2}x_{2}$ and $|p|^{2} = \langle p,p\rangle$. I want to calculate the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{0}|f(t,x)|dt$$
I don't know how to deal with this absolute value. What should I do? Maybe I can transform the first integral into something else?

Comment: Presumably, $x=(x_1, x_2)$ and the integral in question is with respect to $x_1$ and $x_2$ ?

Comment: @Math1000 oops, sorry. Edited the post. The answer to your first question is yes, but the integral is over $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can actually calculate $f(t,x)$ exactly! Note that the integrand is $e^{-g(p_1)-h(p_2)}$ where $g(y)$ and $h(y)$ are quadratic polynomials with positive leading coefficient. Such integrals can be calculated exactly (generalizing the familiar integral $\int_{\Bbb R} e^{-z^2}\,dz$). With the aid of a computer, we find that
$$
f(t,x) = -\frac{2 \pi  }{t}\exp\biggl( -\frac{4 t^4+x_1^2+x_2^2}{4 t^2} \biggr).
$$
Fortunately, this function is always positive when $t<0$, so we can simply remove the absolute value: again with a computer,
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 |f(t,x)|\,dt = \int_{-\infty}^0 -\frac{2 \pi  }{t}\exp\biggl( -\frac{4 t^4+x_1^2+x_2^2}{4 t^2} \biggr)\,dt = 2\pi J_0\Bigl( \sqrt{x_1^2+x_2^2} \Bigr),
$$
where $J_0(z)$ is a [Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Bessel_functions_of_the_first_kind:_J%CE%B1). In case it's helpful,
$$
|J_0(z)| \le \min\biggl\{ 1, \sqrt{\frac2{\pi|z|}} \biggr\}.
$$
Note: the second integration assumed that $(x_1,x_2)\ne(0,0)$; in that case the integral over $t$ does not converge.

Comment: I guess you made a typo : $f(x,t) \propto \exp\left(-t^2 + \frac{|x|^2}{4t^2}\right)$. Also, the normalization factor in front the Bessel function is not the right one (cf. 10.9.19 in https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.9#ii).